# How (or what) do I add a folder to the end of a php file

Tags: php, directory

I've been looking for about a week for the answer, but I can not, for the sake of me, even get a straight answer, mainly because I don't know the exact question, so I thought I'd post an example of the question.

How do I add a directory to the end of a PHP file? Or if it's not a directory, what is it called, and how do I do it?

example: example.com/index.php?directory/some/more/things/

Note the 'index.php?directory/' that's the part I refer to

Thanks in advance
 - Pat

P.S. Links to documentation/tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is one of the links i am talking about, it's on a forum that I control, it is using Xenforo:

http://forum.noxcrew.com/index.php?forums/news-and-information.21/

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What should that "directory" do? Where and to what do you want to add it?

Comment: `end of a php file` you meant end of the URL? cause it may sound like end of the script

Comment: Yes i meant end of url after the .php, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a URL rewriting capabilities in the web server.  These allow the user to pass one URL and the server internally process it as another URL.  For example, the user may type into the browser:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/file.php/somedirectory
```

And internally the server will invoke your program as

```
http://www.yoursite.com/file.php?param=somedirectory
```

The configuration would be web server-dependent.  For example, in apache you would use mod_rewrite, for example, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /file.php\/(.*)$ /file.php?param=$1 [QSA]
```

This is, of course, a very simple example.  You can do a lot more than this.  Have a look at [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for specifics.  Of course, if you're using a different web server (e.g. IIS), then you'll have to look at that server's documentation.

Comment: I updated my question with a live link, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @user1545248 Not quite.  What that link uses is `GET` parameter syntax but without parameters.  When http request is sent, everything after `?` is considered a parameter and passed as such to the program.  In that particular syntax, you could then use in PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for GET-Parameter that you can handle in PHP.

More information can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I understand the GET-Paramater, but in my example, there is no variable like: example.com/index.php?var=foo but how would the GET-Parameter get the directory/some/more/things/ without the 'var='

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do but if your trying to 'send' a direction to a php script then you can use GET variables.

```
index.php?path=directory/some/more/things/
```

Then you can use the follow line to get "directory/some/more/things/" in your script.

```
$_GET['path'];
```

This is done because the 'path' part of the url is a variable name and then after the '=' is the value.

Learn more about GET Variables on the PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php